# I am unable to use a debugger

Tags: debugging, assembly, dos

I have started to learn assembly language. The assembler I am using is NASM. Operating system is windows 7 32 bit on VMWARE. I am learning the language by watching video tutorials in which the instructor is using advance fullscreen debugger. The problem is I don't have the notes he provided to his students in which he gave instruction about how to use AFD. I can't understand the use of AFD. So I decided to go for Ollydebug.

My first assembly programming is a DOS application (COM) file. When I tried to open the COM file in Ollydebug, It says "unable to open the file". I am running Ollydebug as administrator. So can anyone solve eithet of the problem, so I can continue with the tutorial?

1. Tutorial or some documentation on AFD(I googled but unable to find).
   *OR*
2. Why I can't open the COM file in Ollydebug and a way to open it?

Comment: Ollydebug is a 32-bit debugger.  A .com file is a 16-bit program.  You need a 16-bit debugger, like Debug included with older versions of Windows.

Comment: My operating system is windows 7 32 bit. and what I know it don't have Debug included? Can I install it from somewhere? or any other option?

Comment: debug is a DOS program, windows 7 has completely phased out DOS; you just have a command interpreter which is not the same thing.

Comment: Try the Borland Museum to get td.exe.  Ought to be included in the Turbo C download, not sure.

Comment: @Hans Passant : Thanks for the td.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite late to reply to this question but for future reference this link [WeToLearn](http://wetolearn.blogspot.com/) provides a comprehensive tutorials on debugging COM files with AFD
. The Article name is "8086 Assembly Debugging with AFD - Advance Full Screen Debug [PART 1 - BASIC]" . He has explained some useful and basic instructions to start debugging on AFD .

Main keys I would like to mention are `F1` ( Step Over ) , `F2` ( Step In ) and `F4` for help you can find about others on that link.

Look at these links [Basic Debugging](http://wetolearn.blogspot.com/2013/09/8086-assembly-debugging-with-afd.html) and [Advance Debugging](http://wetolearn.blogspot.com/2013/10/8086-assembly-debugging-with-afd-advance.html) using AFD